# <ng-scroll> @viewchild is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator, viewchild

in this code i given dayavailablescroll reference but in ngafterviewinit it is   showing undefined

```
<div class="shifts-rightTable " style="background-color: yellow" [ngClass]="{'tab-active':availData?.length}" >
                <ng-scrollbar #dayavailablescroll  [autoHeightDisabled]='false' track='horizontal'>

                <table class="table" >
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let secondValue of availData;let s = index;">
                            <td>
                                <div class="shift-scheduleWrapper dayLeaveIcons" *ngFor="let thirdValue of secondValue.user_roster_data;let m = index;">
                                    <div class="shift-scheduleList" [ngClass]="{'removeLeftspace':(thirdValue.day_status != 'Exchanged' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Scheduled' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Full day leave' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Exchange-Requested')}" [ngStyle]="{left:thirdValue.starTime + 'px',width: thirdValue.totalWidth + 'px'}" *ngIf="thirdValue.schedule_id  && thirdValue.day_status != 'Holiday' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Weekend' && thirdValue.leave_status != 1 && thirdValue.day_status != 'Full day onduty'" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();setShow(s,m);closeOthers(s,m);selectedId = thirdValue.schedule_id;saveValue({id:availData[s].code,firstname:availData[s].first_name,lastname:availData[s].last_name,timeStart:tableData[s].user_roster_data[m].start_time,timeEnd:availData[s].user_roster_data[m].end_time,name:thirdValue.shift_name,date:cDateValue,schId:thirdValue.schedule_id,photo:availData[s].photo,longDate:this.currentWeek[m],username:availData[s].user_id,schedule:thirdValue.exchange_id});"><div class="shiftIcons" [ngClass]="getCurrent(thirdValue.cell_style_class)" *ngIf="(thirdValue.day_status != 'Scheduled'&& thirdValue.day_status != 'Full day leave' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Full day onduty' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Exchanged' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Exchange-Requested')"><span></span></div>{{thirdValue.start_time}} - {{thirdValue.end_time}}
                                    <hris-schedule-exchange *ngIf="thirdValue.active;" (action)="closeAll()" [ngClass]="{'left-active':m >= (secondValue.user_roster_data.length/2),'right-active':m < (secondValue.user_roster_data.length/2),'top-active': s < (availData.length / 2),'bottom-active':s >= (availData.length / 2)}" [id]="thirdValue.id" (exchangeAction)="enableExchange=true;" (editAction)="showEditForm = true;editStatus = true;dataInput = $event.data;disableAll = true;" [dataInput]="{id:availData[s].code,firstname:availData[s].first_name,lastname:availData[s].last_name,timeStart:availData[s].user_roster_data[m].start_time,timeEnd:availData[s].user_roster_data[m].end_time,name:thirdValue.shift_name,date:this.dayList[m],schId:thirdValue.schedule_id,photo:availData[s].photo,longDate:this.currentWeek[m],username:availData[s].user_id,schedule:thirdValue.exchange_id,sch_id:thirdValue}" [showExchange]="((availData[s].user_id == userData.user_id) && thirdValue.exShow)?true:false" [showEdit]="thirdValue.show"></hris-schedule-exchange>
                                    <div class="exchange-req-icon emp-request" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();saveValue({id:availData[s].code,firstname:availData[s].first_name,lastname:availData[s].last_name,timeStart:tableData[s].user_roster_data[m].start_time,timeEnd:availData[s].user_roster_data[m].end_time,name:thirdValue.shift_name,date:cDateValue,schId:thirdValue.schedule_id,photo:availData[s].photo,longDate:this.currentWeek[m],username:availData[s].user_id,schedule:thirdValue.exchange_id});exchangeView=true;" *ngIf="thirdValue.day_status == 'Exchange-Requested'"></div></div>
                                    <div class="shiftIcons" [ngClass]="getCurrent(thirdValue.cell_style_class)" *ngIf="(thirdValue.day_status != 'Scheduled'&& thirdValue.day_status != 'Full day leave' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Full day onduty' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Exchanged' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Exchange-Requested')" [ngStyle]="{left:thirdValue.starTime + 'px'}"><span></span></div>
                                    <div *ngIf="thirdValue.schedule_id && thirdValue.leave_status == 1 && thirdValue.day_status != 'Holiday' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Weekend' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Full day onduty'" [ngStyle]="{width: thirdValue.totalWidth + 'px',left:thirdValue.starTime + 'px'}" class="shift-scheduleList" [ngClass]="{'removeLeftspace':(thirdValue.day_status != 'Exchanged' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Scheduled' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Full day leave' && thirdValue.day_status != 'Exchange-Requested')}" (click)="thirdValue.active = !thirdValue.active;closeOthers(s,m);selectedId = thirdValue.schedule_id;">
                                        {{thirdValue.start_time}} - {{thirdValue.end_time}}
                                        <hris-schedule-exchange *ngIf="thirdValue.active;" (action)="closeAll()" [ngClass]="{'left-active':m >= (secondValue.user_roster_data.length/2),'right-active':m < (secondValue.user_roster_data.length/2),'top-active': s < (availData.length / 2),'bottom-active':s >= (availData.length / 2)}" [id]="thirdValue.id" (exchangeAction)="enableExchange=true;" (editAction)="showEditForm = true;editStatus = true;dataInput = $event.data;disableAll = true;" [dataInput]="{id:availData[s].code,firstname:availData[s].first_name,lastname:availData[s].last_name,timeStart:availData[s].user_roster_data[m].start_time,timeEnd:availData[s].user_roster_data[m].end_time,name:thirdValue.shift_name,date:cDateValue,schId:thirdValue.schedule_id,photo:availData[s].photo,longDate:onlyDate,username:availData[s].user_id,schedule:thirdValue.exchange_id,sch_id:thirdValue}" [showExchange]="((availData[s].user_id == userData.user_id) && thirdValue.exShow)?true:false" [showEdit]="thirdValue.show"></hris-schedule-exchange>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </ng-scrollbar>
            </div>
```

typescript

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log( this.dayavailablescroll);}//undefined
```

Comment: In the current formatting, this is unreadable. Please re-format and narrow it down. Are the empty `<td></td>`'s really necessary?

Comment: @joosep Parts Formated the code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the element on template in typescript part of the code angular way of doing that would be to access it with `ViewChild` after the the template has finished rendering (using `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook).

```js
@Component({selector: 'someCmp', templateUrl: 'someCmp.html'})
class SomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('dayavailablescroll') scrollElem: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     console.log( this.scrollElem);
  }
}
```

Be aware of conditions when the element may not be searchable. If it's not on the template at the time you query the element, you won't find it.

Feel free to replace ElementRef with `ng-scrollbar` type if there is one.
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/